# Sorting by the index from multiple array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to return the index of a certain object from a multiple array of objects. I'll do my best to explain in code.

So let's say i'm connected to an API that pulls down icecream orders in certain stores, and I want to record that data.

```
const iceCreamOrders = {
  VanillaOrders: vanilla.id,
  ChocolateOrders: chocolate.id,
  MintOrders: mint.id
}

const iceCreamOrdersSort = [];
Object.keys(iceCreamOrders).forEach((key) => {
  if (iceCreamOrders.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const innerObj = {};
    innerObj[key] = iceCreamOrders[key];
    iceCreamOrdersSort.push(innerObj);
  }
});
console.log("ICECREAM", iceCreamOrdersSort);
```

So when I console.log this in my terminal, I get

```
ICECREAM [
 { VanillaOrders: 'firstID-V' },
 { ChocolateOrders: 'firstID-C' },
 { MintOrders: 'firstID-M' }
]

ICECREAM [
 { VanillaOrders: 'secondID-V' },
 { ChocolateOrders: 'secondID-C' },
 { MintOrders: 'secondID-M' }
]
```

So now let's say I want to put the MintOrders in order, and use that as the id.

```
const iceCreamOrders = {
  VanillaOrders: vanilla.id,
  ChocolateOrders: chocolate.id,
  MintOrders: iceCreamOrdersSort
}
```

So 'firstID-M' would be 1, 'secondID-M' would be 2, etc. So if I did `console.log("ORDERS", iceCreamOrders);` it would show:

```
ORDERS {
  VanillaOrders: 'secondID-V',
  ChocolateOrders: 'secondID-C',
  MintOrders: '2'
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Its very unclear what it is you're trying to achieve with that piece of code. Explain what you want in words and I'll help you code it... I think either ways what you're doing there is inefficient.